# Commutative diagrams in blogger

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Is there a way to make commutative diagrams in **Blogger**? I can type basic LaTeX but things that require specific packages like making commutative diagrams seems not to work. I usually use

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
```

to make commutative diagrams.

I guess I will have to edit some code directly into the HTML code of Blogger but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Comment: Blogger does not use latex, but mathjax (or something similar). So your question is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888/675277

Comment: @DG' Hence it is necessary use `xy` package or the old `amscd` :-)